# SockJS increase pool size

Tags: websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am using SocketJS and Stomp to send files over a backend api for being process.
My problem is that the upload function get stuck if more than two upload are done at the same time.

Ex:

- User 1 -> upload a file -> backend is receiving correctly the file
- User 2 -> upload a file -> backend is receiving correctly the file
- User 3 -> upload a file -> the backend is not called until one of the
  previous upload hasn't completed.

(after a minute User 1 complete its upload and the third upload starts)

The error I can see through the log is the following:

```
2021-06-28 09:43:34,884 INFO  [MessageBroker-1] org.springframework.web.socket.config.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats.lambda$initLoggingTask$0: WebSocketSession[11 current WS(5)-HttpStream(6)-HttpPoll(0), 372 total, 26 closed abnormally (26 connect failure, 0 send limit, 16 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(302)-CONNECTED(221)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], **inboundChannel[pool size = 2, active threads = 2**, queued tasks = 263, completed tasks = 4481], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 607], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 14, completed tasks = 581444]
```

It seems clear that the pool size is full:

**inboundChannel[pool size = 2, active threads = 2**

but I really cannot find a way to increase the size.

This is the code:

Client side

```
ws = new SockJS(host + "/createTender");
stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
```

Server side configuration

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketBrokerConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setMessageSizeLimit(100240 * 10240);
        registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(100240 * 10240);
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(20000);
    }
```

I've already tried with changing the configureWebSocketTransport parameters but it did not work.
How can I increase the pool size of the socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbound channel into the WebSocket can be overwritten by using this method:

```java
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(4);
    registration.taskExecutor().maxPoolSize(4)
}
```

[The official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.html#configureClientInboundChannel-org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration-) suggests to have a pool size = number of cores. For sure, since the maxPoolSize is reached then requests are handled through an internal queue. So, given this configuration I can process concurrently 4 requests.

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have to wait 21h before mark it as correct.